# os-prober fails to report my current OS, thus update-grub missed it

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

`os-prober` fails to report my current OS, thus `update-grub` missed the very OS I need when generating the boot menu entries. What's the fix?

The detailed background is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667610/), basically my system was initial setup in BIOS/MBR/CSM mode, Windows 10 is refusing to be installed there, so I have to converted my MBR disk to GPT. But I've lost my Windows 8 boot option [then](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667803/fixing-efi-windows-boot-from-linux#comment1258183_667803).

Now I have my Windows 8 in `os-prober` output thus need to regenerate the boot menu entries again. However, the very OS I'm currently using is missing:

```
$ os-prober 
/dev/sda13@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/sda6:Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (18.04):Ubuntu:linux
/dev/sda7:Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04):Ubuntu1:linux
/dev/sda8:Ubuntu 17.04 (17.04):Ubuntu2:linux

$ update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda13@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sda6
Found Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) on /dev/sda7
Found Ubuntu 17.04 (17.04) on /dev/sda8
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ mount | head -6
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3973480k,nr_inodes=993370,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=803528k,mode=755)
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime)
```

What's the problem and the fix?

BTW, the previous boot menu entries were generated directly under grml64-full release 2020.06.

Comment: Does os-prober detect the 20.4 installation in the older ubuntu versions? Boot into one of them and try it out

Comment: With multiple installs of grub, but with UEFI, only one install will be the default boot in UEFI. You can see it in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. Depending on fstab entry that may not be accessible from your install. It is a three line configfile entry to grub.cfg in one install. Then that grub should have entries for all other installs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/792413/how-to-set-grub-from-second-linux-distribution-as-default-in-uefi-boot

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I understand your point @oldfred, but I don't see it is a problem with grub, but rather os-prober instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ***now*** think it is the default behavior actually, for `os-prober` to probe *other* OS instead of itself. As *"other"* OSs show up under the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` section while the current OS show up in the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` section of the generated the boot menu entries (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`).

I didn't see my own current OS in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` was a problem of my own, and it has nothing to do with `os-prober` and `update-grub`. Sorry, first time using EFI boot and grub2.

Case closed.

Comment: The potential issue with multiple UEFI installs, is that a major grub update that in effect totally reinstall grub will reset the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to that install. You then need to either edit grub.cfg to boot your main working install or boot into main install & totally reinstall grub. But if you reinstall grub, any modifications you made will be lost. I back up 40_custom & /etc/default/grub. I just put copies into /home, so my normal backup includes them. But now I just edit the grub.cfg in the ESP.

Comment: Totally agree with you. IMHO, the goal of grub2 was designed for the showoff purpose only, but not for its usability -- how it can and should be used. The scenario you described is such a common one and is handled in such disastrous way by grub2, is only part of its design flaw. IMHO the generated boot menu entries file /boot/grub/grub.cfg really looks like a childish design, like people littering & spreading all kinds of fancy decorations in the html file, while in fact those fancy decorations and complexity should be hide in the css files, instead of making the html file as complex as hell.